# Asp.Net Core Refresh AzureAD claims

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have an Asp.Net Core 2.1 web application which is using AzureAD to authenticate my users. Within my Startup.cs file, I use the OnTokenValidated event of OpenIDConnectOptions to look up the user in a SQL database and add my own Role claim dependent on the values set in the database.
This works but for the purposes of testing different roles, I have to update the database and then sign-out and back in again to test being in a different role.

To make this easier, I have some buttons which allow the user to choose a new role and thus update the database. Unfortunately, they still need to log out and back in again for the role to affect. Is it therefore possible to either change the Role claim or more simply just refresh the claims from AD and re-fire that OnTokenValidated event which would thus set my role to the new value.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better logging out user and let user logging back to refresh the principle .

Refresh the claims from AD won't work since the roles involved in AAD tokens are Azure resource based , the roles are not related to the user's role in local database .

There is another way you can non-destructively update the user principal, call `context.ReplacePrincipal` and set the `context.ShouldRenew` property to true during the cookie validation process :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.2#react-to-back-end-changes

But as the document shows :

> The approach described here is triggered on every request. Validating authentication cookies for all users on every request can result in a large performance penalty for the app.

So just sign out user and let him sign in back if you make the back end changes.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, I have managed to solve my issue as below. It is not ideal but satisfies my requirement during my testing phase

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to use the following code to achieve my requirement:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeRole(string role)
{
    var principal = HttpContext.User;
    var customIdentity = principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Claims.Any(y => y.Type == ClaimTypes.Role));
    if (customIdentity != null)
    {
        if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Role), role))
        {
            customIdentity.RemoveClaim(customIdentity.Claims.First(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Role));
            customIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }
    }

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(new ClaimsPrincipal(principal));

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```